# Header banner margins css

Tags: css

How can I remove side margins from the template? I searched the CSS files but haven't found anything.

Thanks in advance,
Irina

Comment: What template? What header? What site? Please, give us some idea what we're expected to help with...

Comment: Such a random question. Use firebug, or chrome developer tool and you will find the problem.

Comment: do you just want the site to go to the left rather than centered?

Comment: just the header banner, to move it to the left so that green margin wouldn't show up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's the famous problem of margin and padding

Try this:

```
body{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
}
```

You could try the class that you think is causing the problem too..

If it's not the problem, please paste the code or example for more precision.

Thanks

EDIT : Try to remove the margin-left:50px in the #portfolio And add padding:0px;

```
#portfolio {
list-style: none outside none;

margin-top: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Greg, many thanks for your response. That margin/padding thing didn't work, so here is the full style.css code:

Comment: Looks like they won't let me insert the whole code here :((

Comment: Should do it with the edit i've just add

Comment: Have tried that, but everything looks the same.

Comment: Just to be sure could you try firefox, I'll look for opera at the same time, thanks

Comment: Now that worked with firefox. You're a genius. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, seems to be fixed in opera too, maybe their was some cache, could you please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Alright, have marked it! I am new here so don't know how it works yet. Thanka again.

Comment: Hi Greg! Yesterday you helped me to get rid of that left margin, now I'm having troubles with the right margin. The same algoritm doesn't work for it. Thanks, Irina

Comment: Please open another question, it's not the same problem at all ... and explain what do you want instead of the green margin ... a solution would me maybe to get a larger image